# Retrieving Connection string from Environment Variables

Tags: asp.net-core

For some reason I cannot retrieve connection string from Windows Environment Variables, it returns null value, but it is there.

Here is how I am trying to retrieve it:

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApp5ConnectionStr")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, here it is:

I had to change from:

> Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApp5ConnectionStr")

to

> Configuration["WebApp5ConnectionStr"]

Comment: Your environmental variable has to follow the same structure like your application.json, i.e. `{ "ConnectionStrings" : { "WebApp5ConnectionStr" : "<connectionstringhere>" } }`. When you load it via Configure it's `Configure.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["WebApp5ConnectionStr"]` or  `Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApp5ConnectionStr")` for short.

Comment: So if you want to override this value with an environment variable, you have to name the environmental variable "ConnectionStrings:WebApp5ConnectionStr" not "WebApp5ConnectionStr". In Linux you have to replace the ":" with "_", so "ConnectionStrings:WebApp5ConnectionStr"

Comment: @Tseng Are you saying that this answer is wrong, and simply making the environment variable follow the correct format will work?  Is there a fallback precedence?  I.e. Configuration first checks application.json and then checks environment?

Comment: @pomeroy: It's not necessary do the changes in the answer, just have environment variable named `CUSTOMCONNSTR_WebApp5ConnStr` and then `Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApp5ConnStr")` should work. And yes, there is: First call `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` and then `.AddJsonFile(...)` (exactly opposite to the default setup) in your startup. Last registration overrides values of former ones

Comment: According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables) you should use double-underscore to create a hierarchical configuration using environment variables.